# How to override the Is operator?

Tags: vb.net

I have a bunch of objects scattered in a database. All of them have a numeric ID and I want to override the Is operator so I could do this

```
if objA is objB then ...
```

currently it compares the memory location i think or whatever .net does to keep track of class instances. I want to override it so it would compare the ID's in the objects instead.

Google is of no help since "Is" is filtered out I think.

Comment: Is there any special reason why you need to use the `Is` operator?

Comment: if `If objA.ID = objB.ID` is too easy, you could provide your own comparer (`If objA.Equals(objB) Then..`  `Is` is for comparing the object reference not a single property of an object.

Comment: @Guffa Nope, just for convenience.

Comment: Not possible:Operator is not overloadable. Operator declaration must be one of:  +, -, *, \, /, ^, &, Like, Mod, And, Or, Xor, Not, <<, >>, =, <>, <, <=, >, >=, CType, IsTrue, IsFalse.

Comment: Is can automatically be used with any object type. No need to overload